# Autoresponder Email goes to spam folder using contact form 7 plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form plugin to create a form and to send email. When i click on submit button. auto responder email is goes in spam folder.

my domain is http://buildwealthdaily.net

Comment: Did you tried setting the **Mail(2)** `From` address to `wordpress@buildwealthdaily.net` ?

Answer (score 0):

It happens for various reasons. Usually it is solved by using SMTP to send mail.

This plugin will probably help you: http://www.callum-macdonald.com/code/wp-mail-smtp/